# UITableView inside UITableViewCell changes color to white when selected

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` inside a `UITableViewCell` (Scrolling is disabled for the nested `UITableView`)

Everything works fine. However there is an issue when I tap on the cell. It gets highlighted, but the nested `UITableView` changes its color to white which does not look good.

Is there any way to change this? I already set the nested `UITableView's` `backgroundView` and its `cells` to `transparent`.

EDIT: `Selection` is disabled for the nested `UITableView`. The tap occurs on a cell of the outer `UITableView`, which makes the whole inner `UITableView` turn white.

EDIT2: Here are some screenshots before and during the tap

[image: Before the tap]
[image: During the tap]

EDIT3:
Code of the first `UITableView`:

In the `ViewControler's` `viewDidLoad`

```
    self.tableView.delegate = self
    self.tableView.dataSource = self
    self.tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkBlueColor()
    self.tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "TimelineDay", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: TimelineDayTableViewCell.identifier)
```

In the `TimelineDayTableViewCell's` `awakeFromNib`()

```
    self.tableView.delegate = self
    self.tableView.dataSource = self
    self.tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkBlueColor()
    self.tableView.backgroundView = UIView.clearView()
    self.selectedBackgroundView = UIView.viewWithBackgroundColor(UIColor.accentColor())
    self.tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "EventItemCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: EventItemTableViewCell.identifier)
```

In the `EventItemTableViewCell's` `awakeFromNib`()

```
    self.backgroundView = UIView.clearView()
    self.selectedBackgroundView = UIView.clearView()
```

Comment: can you post your source code?

Comment: It is mostly all set up in storyboard. I try to edit my answer to make it more understandable.

Comment: Please try my answer is done or not?

Comment: Do you have to use an inner `UITableView`? What about `UIStackView`?

Comment: It works now thanks to pedrouan's answer. However I guess I could also use UIStackView. Are there any benefits in terms of performance?

Comment: Of course, it's lighter and faster. There's no delegate methods for populating, scrolling or selecting since it's just regular views. They are used to automatically manage inner constraints and replace manual storyboard layout. If view placements are static it's perfect, and if there's dynamic instanciations you can use it either!

Comment: Thanks, If I have time I'll give it a try...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may need to subclass your cell:

```
class YourTableViewCellClass: UITableViewCell
{        
    @IBOutlet weak var yourLabel: UILabel!

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        if(selected) {

            self.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red //or what you want
            self.yourLabel.textColor = UIColor.green //or what you want

        } else {

            self.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white //or what you want
            self.yourLabel.textColor = UIColor.green //or what you want
        }
    }                
}
```

Comment: Ah, nice! Thank you, this did the trick. I already subclassed UITableViewCell anyway, so this was easy to add.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this, good job:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        var selectedCell:UITableViewCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)!
        cellSelected.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor() }

    // if tableView is set in attribute inspector with selection to multiple Selection it should work.

    // Just set it back in deselect 

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        var cellToDeSelect:UITableViewCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)!
        cellDeselected.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor() }
```

Comment: I tried this code in the inner UITableView, which did not change anything because selection is disabled in the inner UITableView.